# Difference between GBIC and SFP

Tags: networking, switch, trunk, nic

What is the difference between GBIC, SFP, SFP+?

Comment: Both of them are all the same :-)  This is the start of a joke right?

Comment: I meant seriously, better ask then sorry. I don't see something wrong...

Comment: I think all the close votes and down votes are there because you used a bunch of abbreiviations in your question, and gave no background. This makes your question less likely to show up in searches making it less likely that the answer you got is findable and useful for someone else. Please write your questions a bit more fully in future, for the greater good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFP is a smaller form factor of GBIC.

Both GBIC and SFP were designed to be swappable/pluggable interfaces.  SFP (small-form pluggable) is just more efficient in terms of size, with SFP+ being a compatible interface with increased speed.

Comment: thanks. Are there some speed limitations between them?

Comment: No, just a different form factor.  There is a difference in capability between sfp and sfp+ though.  Let me know if you have any other questions or accept the answer please for future googlers :)